# Можно ли значение в KeyStore сохранять при удалении приложения

Tags: android, безопасность, keystore

Есть два приложения с общим префиксом в package. Нужно создать разшаренную зону для хранения общих ID. Это зона в идеале должна сохранятся даже если оба приложения были удалены, но задача минимум сохранить ее если удалено только одно из приложений(дублировать данные нельзя, доступ другим приложениям кроме текущих к ним тоже должен быть закрыт). Можно ли Keystore настроить для подобного поведения?

Comment: А как вы сами пробовали решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пока нет готового решения. Есть либо вариант с использованием KeyStore по отдельности, либо ContentProvider как прокси, Вопрос скорее не о конкретном решении а о подсказке в каком направлении можно было бы двигаться